# When is it appropriate to use the main shader functions with regl?

Tags: shader, void, regl

When constructing your shaders, I notice sometimes a void function named main is constructed is used to define the shader. It seems like `main` is added to the shader when an attributed is iterated on.

I wanted to get some clarity for when it is appropriate to define the shader inside `main` as opposed to just within the top-level definition space of the shader.

Example code from [the regl tutorial](https://regl.neocities.org/02-triangle.html).

```
var drawTriangle = regl({
  //
  // First we define a vertex shader.  This is a program which tells the GPU
  // where to draw the vertices.
  //
  vert: `
    // This is a simple vertex shader that just passes the position through
    attribute vec2 position;
    void main () {
      gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
    }
  `,

  //
  // Next, we define a fragment shader to tell the GPU what color to draw.
  //
  frag: `
    // This is program just colors the triangle white
    void main () {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
  `,

  // Finally we need to give the vertices to the GPU
  attributes: {
    position: [
      [1, 0],
      [0, 1],
      [-1, -1]
    ]
  },

  // And also tell it how many vertices to draw
  count: 3
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with regl, but a `main()` function is always required for GLSL shaders. It is the shader's entry point. For example in the case of the vertex shader, the shader's `main()` function will be executed for each vertex. In your tutorial code, `gl_Position` is a builtin (as opposed to user-defined) output of the vertex shader. `attribute vec2 position;` defines an input variable for the vertex shader which gives access to the `position` attribute.